# ASP.NET MVC 3 Routing Structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

ASP.NET MVC 3 Routing confuses me. I feel like I've read everything I can, but sometimes, I still just don't get it. I am trying to create a URL that I can visit that looks like

```
/authorized/home/children/{childID}
```

I want that URL to show an HTML view that loads the contents for a specific child. My view is defined as follows:

```
/Views/Authorized/Home/Children/Child.cshtml
```

In my global.asax.cs file, I have added the following route:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
    "Child", // Route name
    "{controller}/Home/Children/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Authorized", action = "Child", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

In AuthorizedController.cs, I have the following:

```
public ActionResult Child(string id)
{
  return View("~/Views/Authorized/Home/Children/Child.cshtml");
}
```

If I visit /authorized/home/children, I see the contents of Child.cshtml. However, if I visit /authorized/home/children/1, I get a 404.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Is this the only route you have defined? if not can you please post the rest of the routes?

Comment: All other routes have been commented out in an attempt to isolate the problem. The route registered above is the only route that is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route you shared does not match the route you're saying you're wanting.

You want:

```
/authorized/home/children/{childID}
```

But, you're route is expecting:

```
/Authorized/Home/Children/{action}/{id}
```

Note the additional action parameter there.  Is children your action in your controller, or is it child?  If it's children you should update your route to this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    "Child", // Route name
    "{controller}/Home/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Authorized", action = "Children", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

However, if it's Child you'll need to remove the {action} from your route like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    "Child", // Route name
    "{controller}/Home/Children/{id}",
    new { controller = "Authorized", action = "Child", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

This will make an explicit route, directing to the Child action.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong code from a second project I had open. I have since updated my post.

Comment: Does the second route provided by @Mark Oreta solve your problem though? because it looks like it should.